# connect to mysql with unix socket instead of tcp

Tags: configuration

I'm not looking for the "use `127.0.0.1`" solution. 
I want to run the site on my local development environment and use the unix socket to connect to the database. In my `settings` file I've set the host to `'host' => 'localhost',` and I've tried `'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.socket',` as well, but both result in a `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]` error in the apache logs.

When I connect directly to mysql through the command line I connect through the unix socket, but when I run it through Drupal it only connects through the TCP connection. I am under the impression Drupal will connect through the socket if the `localhost` host name is used, but this doesn't appear to be the case here.

Perhaps there's some other local configuration I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly figured this out after posting. To connect using a socket use `'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock',` not `.socket`.

This allows me to connect to mysql using the unix socket instead of the networking IP address, `127.0.0.1`. This may be an issue with core since I think by default Drupal should connect on this default socket.